# scraping data hurdles with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, screen-scraping

I am working on a scraping and i need to extract the informaion of the websites, basically it is giving link to inside pages

Here is my Small try with scraping, i am able to get the names of the states but i need to go deeper now as i admit, i am very bad at regular expressions

Please guide. here is my code

```
<cfscript>
function stripHTML(str) {
    str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "<*style.*?>(.*?)</style>","","all");
    str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "<*script.*?>(.*?)</script>","","all");
    str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "<.*?>","","all");
    str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "^.*?>","");
    str = reReplaceNoCase(str, "<.*$","");
    return trim(str);
}
</cfscript>
<cfset start = false>
<cfhttp url="http://www.mapsofindia.com/pincode/" method="get"></cfhttp>
<cfset status = cfhttp.Statuscode>
<cfif status IS '200 OK'>
    <cfset start = true>
</cfif>
<cfif start>
    <cfset string = cfhttp.filecontent />
    <cfset StartText = '<table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 align="center" border="0" class=extrtable width="90%">' />
    <cfset Start = FindNoCase(StartText, string, 1) />
    <cfset EndText='<td style="width:50%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><br /><br />' />
    <cfset Length=Len(StartText) />
    <cfset End = FindNoCase(EndText, string, Start) />
    <cfset parse = Mid(string, Start+Length, End-Start-Length) />
    <cfset parse = Insert('+',parse,FindNoCase("</a>", parse))>
    <cfset parse = trim(parse) />
    <cfset dbData = stripHTML(ListQualify(parse,'+'))>
    <cfloop list="#createLst#" index="k" delimiters="+">
        <cfquery name="insert_data" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        INSERT INTO cw_states(state,countrycode,country) 
        VALUES('#k#','IN','India')
        </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
    <table align="center">
        <cfoutput>#parse#<br></cfoutput>
    </tr>
    </table>
</cfif>
```

This is listing the cfoutput on page correctly, but i am unable to insert into the database.

Question #2: The link is taking to another page which lists the cities of the state, i want to append my page like index2.cfm?url=#link# which will extract the cities and insert the cities in my cities table and again on the link it should be like index3.cfm?url=#link# which will open another page of zip and insert those zip names in the database

Please guide

Comment: I recommend you use JSoup instead of trying to do this with regexes. Coincidentally I was working on a similar task on the weekend, and blogged about it. It might help: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/scraps-scrapes-and-soup.html

Comment: +1 for JSoup. I've used it a bunch as well, and it definitely makes scraping and general HTML fragment parsing relatively trivial. If you have a good handle of CSS/jQuery selectors, it's easy to get your head around how to use JSoup.

Comment: JSoup seems good, but with that, i need to spend time to actually learn it all, can now it be done as regex now, as i am running out of timeline